# Chemistry Spreadsheet Software?

Tags: software

Are there any chemistry spreadsheet-like software that:

- Generates 2D structure for the entered compounds (based on name or SMILES)
- Easy to search and create customized reports (such as similarity search)

that preferably runs on linux and is not too expensive?

I'm aware of [ICM Chemist](http://www.molsoft.com/icm-chemist.html) and [JChem for Office](http://www.chemaxon.com/products/jchem-for-office/) (Windows), and I'm wondering if there are any other alternatives available.

Comment: Spreadsheets are for calculations (you can describe functional relationship between cells etc). What kind of calculation / spreadsheet functions do you want to use?

Answer (score 6):

I can't comment on spreadsheet-like tools.

But I'm frequently using [Open Babel](http://openbabel.org/), which is free (as in *free speech* and *free beer*).

If you're not so much into using command-line tools or using programmes via their bindings to programming languages, a [GUI for Open Babel](http://openbabel.org/docs/2.3.1/GUI/GUI.html) is available too, but I've never used it.

> Generates 2D structure for the entered compounds (based on name or SMILES)

Names might be tough in general, but [SMILES](http://www.daylight.com/smiles/) (Simplified Molecular Input Line Entry System) can be processed with Open Babel when the identifier is read from a file. Output to large number of chemical formats and image formats is possible.

`obabel -ismi stuff.smi -omol -O stuff.mol`

would convert a SMILES string to a mol file.

Converting a collection of SMILES to MOL and writing them to a SDF file is not a big thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import pybel

# dictionary of SMILES taken from chemspider.com
insecticides = {
    'parathion' : 'CCOP(=S)(OCC)OC1=CC=C(C=C1)[N+](=O)[O-]',
    'disulfaton' : 'CCOP(=S)(OCC)SCCSCC', 
    'permethrin' : 'C1(C(C1C(=O)OCC2=CC(=CC=C2)OC3=CC=CC=C3)C=C(Cl)Cl)C',
    'furathiocarb' : 'CCCCOC(=O)N(C)SN(C)C(=O)OC1=CC=CC2=C1OC(C2)(C)C',
    'methomyl' : 'CC(=NOC(=O)NC)SC'
}

# write dict items to multi-component SDF file
outdir = '/home/klaus/workspace/chemistry/stackexchange/similarity/'
outname = 'insecticides.sdf'
outpath = os.path.join(outdir, outname)
outfmt = 'sdf'
datafile = pybel.Outputfile(outfmt, outpath, overwrite = True)

for name, smiles in insecticides.iteritems():
    mol = pybel.readstring('smi', smiles)
    mol.title = name
    datafile.write(mol)

datafile.close()
```

---

**EDIT**

> Easy to search and create customized reports (such as similarity search)

For the substructure search, I used the [Drug-likeness NCI subset](http://ligand.info/ligand_info_subset_5.sdf.gz) from [ligand.info](http://ligand.info/). The unpacked SDF file (445.2 MB) has 193,323 entries on 14,757,262 lines (`wc -l`).

From the SDF file, I first generated a binary fastsearch file using

`obabel data.sdf -ofs -O data.fs`

Searches are based on SMILES and SMARTS patterns.

[image: 2-aminobenzothiyzole]

I thought that 2-aminobenzothiazole might be an interesting fragment to search for and with a bit of fiddling, I wrote the suitable SMARTS pattern: `c12ccccc1nc(N)s2`

If in doubt about the correct representation, it is always a good idea to convert the pattern to an image file here: `obabel -:"c12ccccc1nc(N)s2" -opng -O pattern.png`.

The search was performed using:

`obabel -ifs data.fs -s"c12ccccc1nc(N)s2" -osvg -O results.svg -xd -xc5 -xA -xC`

and generated a SVG table with 233 entries.

Comment: Oooh, you've got my attention now. Can't wait to see the substructure analysis thing that you've got up your sleeve ;)

Comment: Thanks. I'm a fan of OpenBabel (and RDkit), but for this case I need to store (and easily-visualize) many types of chemical data, including structures. I'm kind of thinking to role out my own solution (RDKit + SQL database + web interface) but want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You forgot a link. Check the SMARTS pattern where?

Comment: @LDC3 No, I didn't ;) But I added the obabel command to generate a PNG from the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I use ACD/Labs Chemsketch in Windows. There is a version that runs on Linux.

> Linux users can download a compatible version of ACD/ChemSketch
>   Freeware that can be run with Code Weavers' CrossOver Office.

http://www.acdlabs.com/resources/freeware/chemsketch/

Comment: Isn't Chemsketch mainly a drawing program rather than a spreadsheet/database program?

Comment: After looking at JChem and ICM Chemist, I agree ChemSketch does not provide the same functionality that the others do. I do know that it can create structures from SMILES and can name the structures. I'm not certain how well it  translates to common names. It will use 2-methyl-2-propanol instead of t-butanol.